# I lost IRS notice for interest. What are my options?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs

Well, I did owe money to IRS last year and after paying all my taxes and IRS having accepted my tax returns, I thought I was done.

However, I got a follow up mail from IRS saying that I owe them $18 in interest. Now the problem is that I lost that notice. What are my options?

- Can I just pay my money with my tax returns next year?
- If not then, what can I do right now so that I am not in trouble?

Comment: If you don't pay until the due date, the interest will produce compound interest. With 18$ to start with, that's not going to kill you, but be prepared it might become 20$ until next year.

Comment: Give them a call, 1-800-829-1040, I think these instructions are still valid for getting an agent, they're easy to work with.  https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2647542-i-know-the-irs-phone-number-is-800-829-1040-but-how-to-do-you-get-someone-to-actually-answer-the-line